# Delete the disabled accounts since 90 days based on custom attribute value

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I move automatically all ad disabled accounts in OU adding the date of deactivation in `extensionattribute4` with this the script :

```
import-module activedirectory
$timer = (Get-Date)
$TargetOU = "OU=Disabled Accounts,DC=domain,DC=lan"
$DisabledAccounts = get-aduser -filter { enabled -eq $false } -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=EMEA,DC=domain,DC=lan"

ForEach ($account in $DisabledAccounts) {
set-aduser -Identity $account.distinguishedName -add @{extensionAttribute4="$timer"}
}

ForEach ($account in $DisabledAccounts) {
Move-ADObject -Identity $account.distinguishedName -TargetPath $TargetOU
```

But when I want to remove the ad disabled accounts with the reference the date of extensionattribute4 less 90 days with the script :

```
import-module activedirectory
$DaysInactive = 90
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))
$DisabledAccounts = get-aduser -filter { extensionattribute4 -lt $time -and enabled -eq $false } -SearchBase "OU=Disabled Accounts,DC=domain,DC=lan"

ForEach ($account in $DisabledAccounts) {
Remove-ADObject -Identity $account.distinguishedName
}
```

I have got an error :

```
get-aduser : Invalid type 'System.DateTime'.
Parameter name: extensionattribute4
At C:\removedisabledadaccounts.ps1:4 char:21
+ $DisabledAccounts = get-aduser -filter { extensionattribute4 -lt $time -and enab ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Invalid type 'System.DateTime'.
Parameter name: extensionattribute4,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates you are trying to do an operation that the attribute does not accept. When you populated the field in your earlier operation you converted the date to a string with `@{extensionAttribute4="$timer"}`. I can't imagine those attributes are stored as anything other than strings anyway. In fact trying to store the date object ends in similar failure.

Kudos for using `-Filter` but I am sure this is something beyond the `-Filter`/`-LDAPFilter` so you should just have to do some post processing.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $false} -SearchBase "OU=Disabled Accounts,DC=domain,DC=lan" -Properties extensionattribute4 | 
    Where-Object{$time -ge $_.extensionattribute4}
```

Since we need to work with that attribute we need to be sure it is returned in the `-Properties` list.