# Delete disabled users after 30 days

Tags: powershell

In short I am working on some AD clean up and I am trying to delete any user that has been put in the disabled users OU and has been there for more than 30 days. Just wondering if this below should function the way I am expecting or if I'm missing something.

```
$DaysInactive = 30
$InactiveDate = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))

$Users = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "OU LISTED HERE" -AccountInactive -DateTime $InactiveDate -UsersOnly | Select-Object @{ Name="Username"; Expression={$_.SamAccountName} }, Name, LastLogonDate, DistinguishedName

ForEach ($Item in $Users){
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $Item.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
    Write-Output "$($Item.Username) - Deleted"
}
```

Comment: You can always try it out first using the `-WhatIf` parameter on the `Remove-User` cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

This will delete accounts that have not been used in 30 days, days inactive is not the same as days disabled.
Check here for someone who already did this for you.
[Delete the disabled accounts since 90 days based on custom attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629441/delete-the-disabled-accounts-since-90-days-based-on-custom-attribute-value)